# If function is symmetrical about $(3,4)$. Then $\sum^{6}_{r=0}f(r)$

Tags: functions

> If the graph of non constant function is symmetrical about the point $(3,4)$. Then the value of $\sum^{6}_{r=0}f(r) +f(3)$ is

Try: here $f(3)=4$. I did not understand how to find $f(0) f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6)$.

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Comment: It's symmetrical right? What does that tell you about values to the left and right of $f(3)$?

Comment: For left and right of $f(3)$, we get same values. But how to solve after that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry about a point is not the same as symmetry about the line $x=3$. Symmetry about $(3,4)$ means that $$f(0) + f(6) = 2f(3)$$ $$f(1) + f(5) = 2f(3)$$ and $$f(2) + f(4) = 2f(3)$$

Therefore $\sum_{r=0}^{6}f(r)+f(3) = 8f(3)=32$

Comment: I did not understand how to get $f(0)+f(6)=2f(3)$, explain me please. Thanks

Comment: Since the function is symmetric about the point, $f$ of values equidistant from $3$ average to the value of $f(3)$, i.e. $\frac{f(0)+f(6)}{2} = f(3)$.